# What's stopping my command from terminating?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a command line tool for installing Windows services using Node JS. After running a bunch of async operations, my tool should print a success message then quit. Sometimes however, it prints its success message and doesn't quit.

Is there a way to view what is queued on Node's internal event loop, so I can see what is preventing my tool from quitting?

Comment: Do you use `process.exit()` to quit ? Do you handle all the cases in your **async** operations (errors, ...) ? (often, it's the origin of the problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most typical culprit for me in CLI apps is event listeners that are keeping the process alive.  I obviously can't say if that's relevant to you without seeing your code, though.

To answer your more general question, I don't believe there are any direct ways to view all outstanding tasks in the event loop (at least not from JS-land).  You can, however, get pretty close with `process._getActiveHandles()` and `process._getActiveRequests()`.

I really recommend you look up the documentation for them, though.  Because you won't find any.  They're undocumented.  And they start with underscores.  Use at your own peril. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot - these functions are on the right lines, but their output is still pretty opaque. Is there any way to determine which module owns the handles or has event listeners attached?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how you would get at that info. While the output is certainly pretty opaque, you can at least look for clues. For example, if you see something like `_connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:3000'`, you would know there's a server still running somewhere. Pretty far from ideal; hardly even registers as useful, really. Realistically this is just a situation where you more or less need to trust code to do the right thing. I haven't ever observed this behavior sporadically like your question suggests, though.  It's always been easily reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

try to use some tools to clarify the workflow - for example, the https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall or https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback

so, you don't lose the callback called and can catch any erros thrown while executing commands.

I think you also need to provide some code samples that leads to this errors.

Comment: I don't have access to the code in question anymore, but I'm still interested in the answer of how one would view what is queued on Node's event loop in the general case.